# SQLAlchemy backref is blank after changing cell value

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm using Flask-SQLAlchemy and want to create a one-to-many relationship. I have a dumpster class, and each dumpster has a list of pickups. I have a "Pickup History" page where I want to show all previous dumpster pickups. If I change the location name of a dumpster, then the pickups that previously corresponded to that dumpster now show a blank location name, as in the [picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bwE5.png).

It is clear that the dumpster name update was successful, because you can see "WEB" on the right hand side of the screen. I noticed that If I changed the dumpster name back to its original value, then the pickup list works correctly, I'm assuming because it found a dumpster with a name matching the one it was originally assigned to.

Here is my code for updating dumpster information:

```
def update_dumpster(id):
    dump = Dumpster.query.get_or_404(id)
    form = UpdateDumpsterForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        #Update the dumpster information
        dump.location = form.location.data
        dump.lat = form.lat.data
        dump.lng = form.lng.data
        dump.full = form.full.data
        for pickup in dump.pickups:
            pickup.dumpsterLocation = dump.location
        db.session.commit()
```

Originally, I did not include the for loop, but when I noticed my problem, it was my first attempted solution. I also tried `pickup.dumpster.location = dump.location` but that did not fix the problem either.

Here are the classes I use in models.py:

```
class Dumpster(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    location = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    full = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False)
    onRoute = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False)
    lat = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)
    lng = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)
    pickups = db.relationship('Pickup', backref='dumpster', lazy=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Dumpster({}, {})".format(self.id, self.location)

class Pickup(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    time = db.Column(db.String, nullable=True, default='midnight')
    dumpsterLocation = db.Column(db.String, db.ForeignKey('dumpster.location'), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Pickup({}, {}, {})".format(self.id, dumpster.location, self.date)
```

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I finally figured it out. dump.location is updated to the new value but then compared to the old value of pickup.dumpsterLocation. I just decided to make a new variable called old_location and assign it the dump.location value before the new location is set. Then I compare pickup.dumpsterLocation to old_location. whew

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. dump.location is updated to the new value but then compared to the old value of pickup.dumpsterLocation. I just decided to make a new variable called old_location and assign it the dump.location value before the new location is set. Then I compare pickup.dumpsterLocation to old_location. whew

EDIT: just for completeness, this is what I changed the loop to:

```
for pickup in Pickup.query.all():
        if pickup.dumpsterLocation == old_location:
            pickup.dumpsterLocation = dump.location
```